# How to limit the number of cells having the same value or text in them

Tags: excel, google-sheets, spreadsheet

Is it possible to limit the cells with the same value?

I have a spreadsheet that is suppose to give the option of choosing between yes or no:

[image: example]

I have around 40 cells, each cell has a person who can choose yes or no in them.

I want to limit the number of cells that can have yes to 12, so if there are 30 persons that want to change their cell status to yes only the first 12 can do that and the rest wont be able to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this formula in cell G2 `=IF(COUNTIF(E1:E17,"YES")=12,"N0","YES")` and in cell G3 write NO.

After that create a dropdown list with this two cells and drag it down.

When it reaches 12 YES it would only show NO in the selection.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution.

1. Name the range containing the dropdown list options = `YesNo`
2. Name the range containing the Yes No Dropdown lists = `UserSelect`
3. Apply data validation `=YesNo` to entire UserSelect range.
4. Use the following formula for the "Yes" option in `YesNo`

   `=IF(COUNTIF(UserSelect,"Yes")>=12,"No","Yes")`